# email notification using Maildir

Tags: mutt

I've a postfix server to deliver local emails using Maildir format. Inside home users I've

```
cat /home/$USER/.muttrc

set from="user1@example.com"
set realname="user1"
set mbox_type=Maildir
set folder="~/Maildir"
set mask="!^\\.[^.]"
set mbox="~/Maildir"
set record="+.Sent"
set postponed="+.Drafts"
set spoolfile="~/Maildir"
set timeout=30
```

does mutt support notification via shell of new email? Like: "You have X new mails". Because does not run.

Comment: See *MAILCHECK*, *MAIL* or *MAILPATH* here https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Bourne-Shell-Variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
maildir-notification:
```

https://github.com/varogami/maildir-notification/tree/master/scripts

Lightweight bash script that notify new mail from multiple maildir on desktop GUI with notify, on shell, on remote with jabber instant messaging or show on conky system monitor